# If Loop in Python Stopped working, using jupyter?

Tags: python, csv, for-loop, jupyter-notebook

I am importing a CSV file and importing the data. In the code the if loop (`if get_id == 1 :`) stopped working. It was working when I first wrote it. I did some anasylse and I don't think that loop is running. Did I write it properly?

In the CSV the first column have a few ID's in numbers.

```
confirmed_array=[]
total_array=[]
dates_array=[]

with open('dataset1.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    
    print('File has been imported')
    csv_headings = next(csv_reader)
    
    Cumlative_Cases_Total=0
    Cumlative_Cases_Confirmed=0 
    probabal=0 
    
    test=0
    tracker=0

     #cleaning data    
  
    for line in csv_reader:
        for i, x in enumerate(line):
            if len(x)< 1:
                         x = line[i] = 0
    
    for line in csv_reader:
        
        get_id=int(line[0])
        
        new_case=int(line[4])
        prob=int(line[5])
        deaths=int(line[6])
        recovered=int(line[9])
        today_case=int(line[12])
        
       
        if get_id == 1 :
            probabal=probabal+prob
        
            Cumlative_Cases_Total = Cumlative_Cases_Total + today_case + prob
            Cumlative_Cases_Confirmed=Cumlative_Cases_Confirmed+today_case-probbabal
            
            print('')
           
            confirmed_array.append(Cumlative_Cases_Confirmed)
            total_array.append(Cumlative_Cases_Total)
            
            tracker= tracker+1
```

Comment: Have you tried printing get_id with each iteration to check if it actually ever does == 1?

Comment: how do you know it's not running?

Comment: Just as a note there's no such thing as an if loop. Should be if statement.

Comment: @deadshot the arrays were originally empty. I was adding to them in the if statement. When it ran the arrays were empty. I put some print statements at different locations and noticed that the if statement was skipped

Comment: @KelVarnsen thanks for the catch! Noted

Comment: can you post the sample data you have tested

Comment: @deadshot I am a bit new here, how do I do that?

Comment: add the data you are using the post. I mean sample data from `dataset1.csv`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out ( I think )

The problem looks to be in this section

```
        for i, x in enumerate(line):
            if len(x)< 1:
                         x = line[i] = 0
```

When the code runs, this makes line go to the end. So when it gets to the next section, the section is skipped.  Instead I wrote the code like this :

```
confirmed_array=[]
total_array=[]
dates_array=[]

with open('dataset1.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    
    print('File has been imported')
    csv_headings = next(csv_reader)
    
    Cumlative_Cases_Total=0
    Cumlative_Cases_Confirmed=0 
    probabal=0 
    
    test=0
    tracker=0

    
    for line in csv_reader:
        
        for i, x in enumerate(line):
            if len(x)< 1:
                         x = line[i] = 0
        
        get_id=int(line[0])
        
        new_case=int(line[4])
        prob=int(line[5])
        deaths=int(line[6])
        recovered=int(line[9])
        today_case=int(line[12])
```